# Regex working fine in C# but not in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following javascript code:

```
var markdown = "I have \(x=1\) and \(y=2\) and even \[z=3\]"
var latexRegex = new RegExp("\\\[.*\\\]|\\\(.*\\\)");
var matches = latexRegex.exec(markdown);

alert(matches[0]);
```

matches has only matches[0] = "x=1 and y=2" and should be:

```
matches[0] = "\(x=1\)"
matches[1] = "\(y=2\)"
matches[2] = "\[z=3\]"
```

But this regex works fine in C#.

Any idea why this happens?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Specify `g` flag to match multiple times.

  - Use [String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of [`RegExp.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).
- Using regular expression literal (`/.../`), you don't need to escape `\`.
- `*` matches greedily. Use non-greedy version: `*?`

---

```
var markdown = "I have \(x=1\) and \(y=2\) and even \[z=3\]"
var latexRegex = /\[.*?\]|\(.*?\)/g;
var matches = markdown.match(latexRegex);
matches // => ["(x=1)", "(y=2)", "[z=3]"]
```

Comment: @CrazyCasta, Without `g` flag, `match` returns an array with single item (the first match). (Assuming there's no capturing group)

Comment: @CrazyCasta, `Regexp` object does not have `match` method, but `String` does.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `match` function instead of the `exec` function. `exec` only returns the first string it finds, `match` returns them all, if the global flag is set.

```
var markdown = "I have \(x=1\) and \(y=2\) and even \[z=3\]";
var latexRegex = new RegExp("\\\[.*\\\]|\\\(.*\\\)", "g");
var matches = markdown.match(latexRegex);

alert(matches[0]);
alert(matches[1]);
```

If you don't want to get `\(x=1\) and \(y=2\)` as a match, you will need to use non-greedy operators (`*?`) instead of greedy operators (`*`). Your RegExp will become:

```
var latexRegex = new RegExp("\\\[.*?\\\]|\\\(.*?\\\)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try non-greedy: `\\\[.*?\\\]|\\\(.*?\\\)`. You need to also use a loop if using the `.exec()` method like so:

```
var res, matches = [], string = 'I have \(x=1\) and \(y=2\) and even \[z=3\]';
var exp = new RegExp('\\\[.*?\\\]|\\\(.*?\\\)', 'g');
while (res = exp.exec(string)) {
    matches.push(res[0]);
}
console.log(matches);
```